# Output Shows 0 after Calculating

Tags: java

> State University charges $90.00 for each semester hour of credit,
> $200.00 per semester for a regular room, $250.00 per semester for an
> air-conditional room, and $400.00 per semester for food. All students
> are charged a $30.00 matriculation fee. Graduating students must also
> pay a $35.00 diploma fee. Write a program to compute the fees that
> must be paid by a student. Your program should include an appropriate
> warning message if a student is taking more than 21 credit hours or
> fewer than 12 credit hours. A typical line of data for one student
> would include room type (R or A), student number (in four digits),
> credit hours, and graduation status (T or F).

this is my code:

```java
package Assignment.Q86;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q086 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int matriculation = 30, food = 400, hour, room = 0, graduation = 0, sum;
        String roomType, graduationStatus;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(
            "Your food cost $400.\nYour matriculation cost $30.\n"
        );

        System.out.println("Enter your semester hour:");
        hour = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter room type you want(A or R):");
        roomType = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter your graduation status(T or F):");
        graduationStatus = input.next();

        //semester time
        if (hour < 12 && hour > 21) {
            System.out.println(
                "Alert!! Your semester hour is more or less than the usual.\n"
            );
        } else {
            hour = hour * 90;
        }

        //choosing room type
        if (roomType == "A" || roomType == "a") {
            room = 250;
        } else if (roomType == "R" && roomType == "r") {
            room = 200;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct room type");
        }

        //working for choosing the graduation type
        if (graduationStatus == "T" || graduationStatus == "t") {
            graduation = 35;
        } else if (graduationStatus == "F" || graduationStatus == "f") {
            graduation = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                "Please enter the correct graduation status value"
            );
        }

        sum = matriculation + food + room + hour + graduation;

        System.out.println("your total fees is " + sum);
        System.out.println(" your student number is ****");
        System.out.println("your room type is " + room);
        System.out.println("your graduation status is " + graduation);
        System.out.println("your total credit hours is " + hour);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I clicked any of the room type and graduation status = T. the result of both graduation and room shows the value of 0. The program says that the room and graduation has to be initialize  in order to work.

this is the output example

```
Your food cost $400.
Your matriculation cost $30.

Enter your semester hour:
12
Enter room type you want(A or R):
r
Enter your graduation status(T or F):
t
Please enter the correct room type
Please enter the correct graduation status value
your total fees is 1510
your student number is ****
your room type is 0
your graduation status is 0
your total credit hours is 1080
```

Comment: `graduationStatus == "T"` is not how you compare Strings in Java

Comment: does it work with 'a'?  if so, notice the difference between your `if (` blah blah `== a`)` statement and `else if(`blah blah `== r)` statement

Comment: before this i had did like this:
 if (roomType == 'A' || roomType == 'a')
but the program show error to run them so that why i change so after searching in the google. if these is invalid , so what is the solution for it?

Comment: 1) Use  for example `char roomType = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().chartAt(0)`; 2) Compare with single quotes

Comment: In the 'a' branch you use `||`, in 'r' you use `&&`.  one is OR, one is AND.  RoomType cannot equal 'R' AND 'r'.  (I think your first try (that you mention in the comment) didn't work because you need double quotes for string, single quotes for char.)

Comment: oh so sorry, i accidently type that one. Now, i used || in all of it. i output them again but still no changes in the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`==` is not a good way to compare content. It merely compares references in case of Java. Try using the equals() method for content equality.

Sidenote: Try to break down your code into functions for better readability.

Replace your string comparisons with equals method where you're comparing content.

Ex: `graduationStatus == "T" || graduationStatus == "t"` changes to `graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("t")`

Comment: if(graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("t"))       {              graduation = 35;        }
else if(graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))     {              graduation = 35;        }
else if(graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))    {              graduation = 0;        }
else if(graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))      {              graduation = 0;        }

Comment: shall i do like this above one?

Comment: @ShangkariSha `graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("t")` and `graduationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("T")` give the same result (as the name implies, they ignore uppercase and lowercase), so you can just use one, no need for both.

Comment: i just edited the code and output them. it works finally the output.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. you help save my day.